# How to concat one column by order after group by?

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, concatenation, hiveql

The dataset looks like this:

| id | result | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | pass | 2 |
| 002 | fail | 3 |
| 001 | fail | 1 |
| 002 | pass | 1 |

What I want to do:  group the dataset by id and concatenate the results in ascending order of rank column.

| id | results |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | fail-pass |
| 002 | pass-fail |

As the other column's order is involved, the `concat_ws('-',collect_set(result))`function cannot fulfill my thought.

Are there any built-in functions to help me achieve this, or writing a UDF seems the only solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a subquery before collect_set, distribute by id and sort by id, rank. Dataset will be distributed between reducers by id and sorted by rank before aggregation. See comments in the code.

Demo:

```
with demo_dataset as ( --Use your table instead of this CTE
select stack(4,
'001' , 'pass', 2,
'002' , 'fail', 3,
'001' , 'fail', 1,
'002' , 'pass', 1
) as (id,result,rank)
)

select id, concat_ws('-',collect_set(result))
from
(
select t.* 
  from demo_dataset t
distribute by id   --Distribute by grouping column
sort by id, rank   --Sort in required order
) s
group by id
```

Result:

```
id  results
001 fail-pass
002 pass-fail
```

Now if you change SORT: `sort by id, rank desc` you will get results ordered differently

Answer (score 0):

The answer above can solve the problem, however, it does not fit some situation, for example, if you want to create a column with concat string like this:
"fail:1,sucess:2", the answer above cannot sort the data in order.
Alternatively, I found a solution, you can use
sort_array(collect_set(your_column_name))) to sort the result in order after your group by operation.